# Getting a SqlLite query in String Format from Cursor

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a web service which returns the Cursor Object. I have to access the SqlLite  query from that cursor. Is it possible?

Comment: Do try is the best thing i think:)

Answer (score 0):

No.

You'd have to change the web service to return the query, too.

Answer (score -1):

I think you just have to iterate over the cursor to get the desired results from it, which is like

```
if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            do {
                String your_column = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_NAME));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    cursor.close();
```

Comment: this retrievs the query-result-content. the question was "how to get the [sql]-query that genarates the cursor"

Comment: Oh.. Okay. My bad. Sorry